# info window within jQuery reel images

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jQuery reel to show a building and rotate it. 
I have been able to show the tooltip on a link but I want to show an info window on mouse hover to show the details with images and text (table may be).
This is what I have done so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#TNO3503Div").tooltip({ effect: 'slide'});

  $('#image')
  .reel({
    images:      'http://rishad.me.uk/reel/TimesHouse/###.png',
    frames:      23,
    annotations:
    {
      "TNO3503":
      {
        link: 
        {
          text: "Location", href:'#', class: "mytooltip", 
          title: 'This is the info window where I want to put some details and images.',
        },
        x: 20,
        y: 190
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.mytooltip{
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font-size:18px;
  color:#fff;
}

.mytooltip:hover:after{
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 26px;
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(title);
  left: 20%;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 140px;
  height: 110px;
  display:inline; 
  position:absolute;
}

.mytooltip:hover:before{
  border: solid;
  border-color: #333 transparent;
  border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  bottom: 20px;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
} 

/* trigger button */
#TNO3503Div {
  background:transparent url(http://jquerytools.github.io/media/img/downloadnow.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
  display:block;
  height:44px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-indent:-999em;
  width:159px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

/* mouseover state */
#TNO3503Div:hover {
  background-position:0 -44px;
}

/* clicked state */
#TNO3503Div:focus {
  background-position:0 -88px;
}

/* tooltip styling */
.tooltip {
  display:none;
  background:url(http://jquerytools.github.io/media/img/tooltip/black_arrow_big.png);
  height:163px;
  padding:40px 30px 10px 30px;
  width:310px;
  font-size:11px;
  color:#fff;
}

/* a .label element inside tooltip */
.tooltip .label {
  color:yellow;
  width:35px;
}

.tooltip a {
  color:#ad1;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel.js"></script>

<img id="image" src="http://rishad.me.uk/reel/TimesHouse/001.png" width="500" height="250" />
<br>
<div id="TNO3503Div">Download now</div>
<div class="tooltip">
  <table style="margin:0">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Row1</td>
      <td>Row 1 column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Row2</td>
      <td>Row 2 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Row3</td>
      <td>Row 3 Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Row4</td>
      <td>Row 4 Column 4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need 3 things:

1. use jquery ui to create a tooltip 
   (You can overwrite the standard tooltip css with your own if you like)
2. jQuery script to add extra text and an image
3. An annotation

(also in your example you were missing the class="reel")

```js
        $(function(){ // when DOM ready
            return;
            $('#image').reel({
                stitched:    1500,
                orientable:  true
            });
        });
        //2. The script to add text and image to a tooltip
        $(function() {
            $( document ).tooltip({
                items: "[title]",
                content: function() {
                    var element = $(this);
                    if (element.is("[title]")) {
                        return "<div><h5>example text</h5><img class='photo' src='http://www.newhdwallpapers.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Architectural-3D-Building.jpg'></div>";
                    }
                }})
        });
```

```css
        .photo {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reel demo</title>
    <!--1. CSS for jquery tooltip-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--1. script for jquery tooltip-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    

    <!--3. Add an anotation to the picture like this :-->
    <a class="reel-annotation"
       href="#"
       data-x="160"
       data-y="86"
       data-for="image" title="extra text">
        Example anotation
    </a>


</head>
<body>

<img src="http://www.newhdwallpapers.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Architectural-3D-Building.jpg" width="590" height="590"
     class="reel"
     id="image"
     data-image="http://www.newhdwallpapers.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Architectural-3D-Building.jpg"
     data-stitched="1652"
     data-orientable="true">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It looks great, I have updated my question to show a custom tooltip, but I am unable to add this tooltip inside the image. I will try your code, could you please rectify my code to make the custom tooltip appear inside reel image. Thanks